# Redirect "date" link in .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like that links like: https://www.mywordpresssite.com/2017/08/28 are rewriten and redirected to:  https://www.mywordpresssite.com/date-archives/2017/08/28. Idea is to put those "dates" links in robots.txt so if there is "date-archives" in the link I will be able to write simple regular expression supported by robots.txt.

This is what I tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^/date-archives/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ https://www.mywordpressite.com/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

So, if someone tries to go to `www.mysite.com/2017/08/28` it should be redirected to `www.mysite.com/date-archives/2017/08/28` and that page should open same content as  `www.mysite.com/2017/08/28` page would.

EDIT:
I made plugin which handles rewrites:

```
 <?php
 /**
   *Plugin Name: SEO-date-archives-pages
 *Plugin UIR: 
   *Author: VP
 */
 add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule_example');
 function rewrite_rule_example() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^date-archives/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)', '^([0-
9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)', 'top');

}
```

?>

I am new to wordpress so I am really confused where is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are redirecting in reverse.

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/?$ /date-archives/$0 [R=301,L,NE]

# remaining Wordpress rules go below this
```

Your rewrite rule:

```
<?php
 /**
   *Plugin Name: SEO-date-archives-pages
 *Plugin UIR: 
   *Author: VP
 */
 function rewrite_rule_example() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^date-archives/(\d+/\d+/\d+)/?$', '$matches[1]', 'top');    
 }
 add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule_example');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, just needed to put parentheses RewriteRule ^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)?$ /date-archives/$1 [R=301,L,NE]. BTW, do you know in wordpress is it possible to changes generated "date-link", so I don't have to use redirects at all?

Comment: Sorry, it seems it doesn't work. Redirection works but I get 404 instead of content from "original" page

Comment: There is no such option for dates.Just for "post" pages. But I don't understand why rewrite does not work. Rewriten link should behave as "real" link if rewritten correctly

Comment: No, I have link www.mysite.com/2017/08/28. I want to rewrite and redirect it to: www.mysite.com/date-archives/2017/08/28. I WANT date-arhives part in the url so I can make easier to put rule inside robots.txt (as explained in post)

Comment: If I have https://www.mywordpresssite.com/2017/08/28 user should be redirected to https://www.mywordpresssite.com/date-archives/2017/08/28 and he should not get 404

Comment: I get 404. I get redirected with this:  RewriteRule ^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)?$ /date-archives/$1 [R=301,L,NE]. But I see no "original "content just 404

Comment: This is redirection only. Not rewrite. Rewriten URL means. I have this URL /date-arhives/year/month/date but under the hood there is /year/month/date which wordpress knows how to handle!

Comment: I made plugin (code in edited question) which uses rewrite api, but still no success

Comment: Yes I already solved problem. Still answer accepted because your effort